# coursera progfun1: scala union performance

Tags: performance, scala, functional-programming, time-complexity

when working on the assignment of week 3 of the course 'Functional Programming Principles in Scala' @ coursera I found out that when I implement the function union as shown in the video course :

```
  override def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = {
    left union(right) union(that) incl(elem)
  }
```

it takes too long during execution, however when I implement it this way:

```
  override def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = {
    right.union(left.union(that)).incl(elem)
  }
```

it takes less time during execution and I get full score.

the problem is that I can't figure what's the difference between theses two implementations, how is one faster than the other?

the code given for the assignment (with the implementations of the used data structures) is :

```
package objsets

import TweetReader._

/**
 * A class to represent tweets.
 */
class Tweet(val user: String, val text: String, val retweets: Int) {
  override def toString: String =
    "User: " + user + "\n" +
    "Text: " + text + " [" + retweets + "]"
}

/**
 * This represents a set of objects of type `Tweet` in the form of a binary search
 * tree. Every branch in the tree has two children (two `TweetSet`s). There is an
 * invariant which always holds: for every branch `b`, all elements in the left
 * subtree are smaller than the tweet at `b`. The elements in the right subtree are
 * larger.
 *
 * Note that the above structure requires us to be able to compare two tweets (we
 * need to be able to say which of two tweets is larger, or if they are equal). In
 * this implementation, the equality / order of tweets is based on the tweet's text
 * (see `def incl`). Hence, a `TweetSet` could not contain two tweets with the same
 * text from different users.
 *
 *
 * The advantage of representing sets as binary search trees is that the elements
 * of the set can be found quickly. If you want to learn more you can take a look
 * at the Wikipedia page [1], but this is not necessary in order to solve this
 * assignment.
 *
 * [1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree
 */
abstract class TweetSet {

  /**
   * This method takes a predicate and returns a subset of all the elements
   * in the original set for which the predicate is true.
   *
   * Question: Can we implment this method here, or should it remain abstract
   * and be implemented in the subclasses?
   */
    def filter(p: Tweet => Boolean): TweetSet = ???

  /**
   * This is a helper method for `filter` that propagetes the accumulated tweets.
   */
  def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet

  /**
   * Returns a new `TweetSet` that is the union of `TweetSet`s `this` and `that`.
   *
   * Question: Should we implment this method here, or should it remain abstract
   * and be implemented in the subclasses?
   */
    def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = ???

  /**
   * Returns the tweet from this set which has the greatest retweet count.
   *
   * Calling `mostRetweeted` on an empty set should throw an exception of
   * type `java.util.NoSuchElementException`.
   *
   * Question: Should we implment this method here, or should it remain abstract
   * and be implemented in the subclasses?
   */
    def mostRetweeted: Tweet = ???

  /**
   * Returns a list containing all tweets of this set, sorted by retweet count
   * in descending order. In other words, the head of the resulting list should
   * have the highest retweet count.
   *
   * Hint: the method `remove` on TweetSet will be very useful.
   * Question: Should we implment this method here, or should it remain abstract
   * and be implemented in the subclasses?
   */
    def descendingByRetweet: TweetList = ???

  /**
   * The following methods are already implemented
   */

  /**
   * Returns a new `TweetSet` which contains all elements of this set, and the
   * the new element `tweet` in case it does not already exist in this set.
   *
   * If `this.contains(tweet)`, the current set is returned.
   */
  def incl(tweet: Tweet): TweetSet

  /**
   * Returns a new `TweetSet` which excludes `tweet`.
   */
  def remove(tweet: Tweet): TweetSet

  /**
   * Tests if `tweet` exists in this `TweetSet`.
   */
  def contains(tweet: Tweet): Boolean

  /**
   * This method takes a function and applies it to every element in the set.
   */
  def foreach(f: Tweet => Unit): Unit
}

class Empty extends TweetSet {
    def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet = ???

  /**
   * The following methods are already implemented
   */

  def contains(tweet: Tweet): Boolean = false

  def incl(tweet: Tweet): TweetSet = new NonEmpty(tweet, new Empty, new Empty)

  def remove(tweet: Tweet): TweetSet = this

  def foreach(f: Tweet => Unit): Unit = ()
}

class NonEmpty(elem: Tweet, left: TweetSet, right: TweetSet) extends TweetSet {

    def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet = ???


  /**
   * The following methods are already implemented
   */

  def contains(x: Tweet): Boolean =
    if (x.text < elem.text) left.contains(x)
    else if (elem.text < x.text) right.contains(x)
    else true

  def incl(x: Tweet): TweetSet = {
    if (x.text < elem.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left.incl(x), right)
    else if (elem.text < x.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left, right.incl(x))
    else this
  }

  def remove(tw: Tweet): TweetSet =
    if (tw.text < elem.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left.remove(tw), right)
    else if (elem.text < tw.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left, right.remove(tw))
    else left.union(right)

  def foreach(f: Tweet => Unit): Unit = {
    f(elem)
    left.foreach(f)
    right.foreach(f)
  }
}

trait TweetList {
  def head: Tweet
  def tail: TweetList
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def foreach(f: Tweet => Unit): Unit =
    if (!isEmpty) {
      f(head)
      tail.foreach(f)
    }
}

object Nil extends TweetList {
  def head = throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException("head of EmptyList")
  def tail = throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException("tail of EmptyList")
  def isEmpty = true
}

class Cons(val head: Tweet, val tail: TweetList) extends TweetList {
  def isEmpty = false
}


object GoogleVsApple {
  val google = List("android", "Android", "galaxy", "Galaxy", "nexus", "Nexus")
  val apple = List("ios", "iOS", "iphone", "iPhone", "ipad", "iPad")

    lazy val googleTweets: TweetSet = ???
  lazy val appleTweets: TweetSet = ???

  /**
   * A list of all tweets mentioning a keyword from either apple or google,
   * sorted by the number of retweets.
   */
     lazy val trending: TweetList = ???
  }

object Main extends App {
  // Print the trending tweets
  GoogleVsApple.trending foreach println
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an explanation [here.](https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun1/discussions/weeks/3/threads/AzJ-4CLYEeag6wpD-92Rcw)

basically when we do

```
 left union(right) union(that) incl(elem)
```

first `left union (right)`
is processed, then `union(that)` is processed,
so we are making the tree on the left side of the second `union` bigger, which will take more time to finish the recursion because the recursion ends when the left argument of `union` is empty (check the implementation of `union` in the class `Empty` ).

Answer (score 3):

I posted an explanation [here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun1/discussions/weeks/3/threads/AzJ-4CLYEeag6wpD-92Rcw/replies/NsyjCSMIEeaSbhIJy3C38Q/comments/NqN3gXxxEeagQhLtAgFLAw)

*Here is its content :*

Some notation :

Root : The root element of the tree.
Left/Right : Either the left/right tree if we speak of an union, element if we speak of the "incl left"

**A. Meaning of (left union (right union (other incl elem)))**

First : You incl the current visited node in other (this explore the tree, go down the right leaf, and add your item to Other. No need to call union in it)

Second : You repeat that step with the right subtree.

Third : You repeat that step with the left subtree.

GLOBAL MEANING : Each time, you add your current elem to other, and then you try go right. If you can, you add the right element to other, and again until you can't go right. Then, you try to go left ... You could ? Go right again ! You can't ? Can't go left either ? BACKTRACK.

You can see that as a "prioritized movement". Each time you add your item, then by preference you go right, then left, then go back and repeat ! By doing this, you explore only once the whole tree and for each node you add it to other !

**B. Meaning of ((left union right) union other) incl elem (or left union right union other)**

Just lol. In brief, you want to add the current item you have, that you could add NOW in oher, AT THE LAST STEP POSSIBLE. But this isn't the worst part. When you call (left union right), you are now adding the left item to the right subtree, by the same inefficient way you've done before. Which means : You haven't yet included elem to other, but you will have to include left.item to right. And then, since you will call (left.left union left.right), have to include left.left.item to left.right .. Each time you do A.union(B), you remove an item of A by copying it entirely (and not a smart copy like the immutable set returned by an incl method) and then add it to B. But since removing the item of A needs to call A.left.union(A.right), you will first have to copy A.left/A.right ... And so on. If you can visualize a tree, it's like gathering each left brother to its right brother, and that each time you want to add only one item to other.

SOME NOTES :

If you can say that a empty.union(that) = that, you can say that NonEmpty.union(that : TweetSet) = if that is empty then this then (((union ... ) .. ) other incl elem). That's the problem with methods and such Empty/NonEmpty pattern, you can't centralize those two base case in a single method, and here, a lot of us implement the first one in empty but forgot the other in NonEmpty. ALWAYS be sure that if A.f(b) is symmetric (= b.f(A)), you have the both base cases implemented
Identify and go straight to your base case. Then, do the recursion from it to your global solution. for "left union right union other incl elem", the base case is other incl elem, since you wan't your substitution to be at the end "Empty incl n1 incl n2 incl ...". So focus on it, (other incl elem) directly.
lastly, but more importantly : Intuition !!! Use really simple case, for example, if you have difficulty with my explanation here, imagine the same argument for the "copy" method that you could write as (left copy right) incl elem or (left copy (right incl elem)). With a simple example like this, you can use the substitutions more easily and quickly see why some solutions are dramatically worst than other !
Hope it will help some ! If you have remarks, tell me !